# How can I add a button + Plain Text after the last item in ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very new to android development and android studio; I will try to express my question as clear as possible. If I am using the wrong terminology when referring to some things please let me know along your answer.

**What do I want to do?:**

I want to create a list of items from an array of strings whose values I have stored in arrays.xml. I want the user to select which of these strings to use by checking a box next to each of them. Additionally I want to add the following after the last item in my array:

[+] _Add_your_own_item__

(The user would write a String and press the [+] button, this will add a new item to the list above with a box to tick as well).

I want this Button + Plain Text to be inside of the ListView that contains the list, as if this Button + text is the last item in the list.

**What Have I been able to do so far?:**

I have managed to create a dynamic list of checkboxes for all the elements of my array:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_characters);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        characters = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.characters);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, characters);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        for(int i = 0; i < characters.length; ++i)
        {
            listView.setItemChecked(i, false);
        }
    }
```

I have tried to create the Button + Plain Text directly modifying the .xml file for my activity, but it just places them outside of the ListViex.

From my very limited understanding my ArrayAdapter turns each string into a "checkbox" view, and places them one below the other in the ListView; how can I do the same for a Button + Text? I only need a push into the right direction, I can then try to figure out the logic to add my new string into the list of checkboxes.

Here is hoy my layout is so far: (That Button in there just tells my which Strings are selected)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/characters"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:onClick="getSelectedSuspects"
        android:text="@string/continue_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checksContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Override the getview method of your adapter and modify the layout you inflate accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way with ListView is to set a footer view.  A footer view is inside the list and scrolls with it, but is not counted as an element of the list.  Use `listView.addFooterView(view)` to add it.  The view is typically inflated from xml via a LayoutInflater.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please take a look at how I solved my problem? May I ask how can I make the "+" button just be the size of the "+" symbol, wrap_content seems to still be much larger than just the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is in the position I was a couple of hours ago: I will add a more novice friendly response based on what I understood from @Game's answer.

I created a new layout, which would be inserted itself as another ViewGroup at the bottom of my ListView. For the examples in my question that would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayCharactersActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Add a suspect"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then, in the OnCreate() method of your activity add:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_button_text, listView, false);
        listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

I don't understand all the details behind this lines, but it "appends" this ViewGroup at the bottom of the ListView; if anybody wants to explain this in more detail please feel free to edit.